# why codeigniter not showing my view, just 404 not found?

Tags: php, codeigniter, backend

I am new in codeigniter.i'm trying to linked another view, but codeigniter not showing my view.here is my view code.

```
<div class="logo">
        <img src="<?= base_url('assets/') ?>img/kliniku.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <ul class="navigasi">
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url('auth/login') ?>">login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

here is my controller code 'auth.php'

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('auth/login');
    }
}
```

thank you for helping me.

Comment: why `crud` or `web-site-projet` tags (see their definitions) ???

Comment: What is the file name and path of view ?

Comment: you have a typo: your link should be  `<a href="<?= base_url('auth/index') ?>">login</a>`

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please further elaborate on what your problem is so we can help you better. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: views/auth/login

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Xampp check your project folder
in your htaccess file you have to set RewriteBase to your folder name

```
RewriteBase /YOUR_PROJECT/
```

check your config file in application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url']  =  "";
```

check route file in application/config/route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'YOUR_Control_NAME';
```